# Binary variable notation

Tags: combinatorics, notation, computer-science, binary

Suppose we have a memory element, i.e., a Flip Flop ($FF$).

A $FF$ can have a current value of binary $0$ or $1$, i.e., $FF \in \{0, 1\}$.

Is there any formal way to represent three types of $FF$s:

*if the current $FF$ state is $0$ then it transitions to $1$ but if the current $FF$ state is $1$ then it stays at $1$.*

*if the current $FF$ state is $1$ then it transitions to $0$ but if the current $FF$ state is $0$ then it stays at $0$.*

*if the current $FF$ state is $1$ then it transitions to $0$ and if the current $FF$ state is $0$ then it tranistions to $1$.*

I was thinking I could use bar like $\overline{FF_1} = 0 \rightarrow 1$ , $1 \rightarrow 1$

And to represent the opposite:  $\underline{FF_2} = 1 \rightarrow 0$ , $0 \rightarrow 0$

And to represent the last type:  ${FF_2|} = 1 \rightarrow 0$ , $0 \rightarrow 1$

However, I am sure this does not look formal and right.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you are looking for the boolean operators AND, OR, and NOT, where the first, second, and third types are $FF +1$, $FF \cdot 0$, and $\overline{FF}$.

The reason why the first type is $FF + 1$ is because, regardless of the value of $FF$, $FF + 1$ returns $1$. Similar to this is the second type where, regardless of the value of $FF$, $FF \cdot 0$ returns $0$. For the third type, we just used the NOT operator.

---

The AND boolean operator returns a $1$ if and only if all inputs are $1$, otherwise it returns $0$. The OR boolean operator returns a $0$ if and only if all inputs are $0$, otherwise it returns a $1$. Finally, the NOT boolean operator returns a $0$ if the input is $1$ and returns a $1$ if the input is $0$.